# How to apply Self Join

Tags: mysql, join, self-join

Schema:

Student (snum: integer, sname: char(30), major: char(25), level: char(2), age: integer)

Faculty (fid: integer, fname: char(30), deptid: integer)

Class (cname: char(40), meets_at: char(20), room: char(10), fid: integer | fid REFS
Faculty.fid)

Enrolled (snum: integer, cname: char(40) | snum REFS student.snum, cname REFS
class.name)

I want to print the level and the age of students for all levels
except 'JR'. I know I can apply this query in a simple way. But I want to us e JOINS

My attempt:

```
select s.levels as Seniority,s.age as Age

from student s

where s.levels not in (

select a.levels

from student a

where a.levels='JR');
```

This is not giving me expected answer. Am I doing some mistake?

Comment: you don't want `join` ?!!

Comment: I want to do this by JOINS

Comment: like this `Select s.level, s.age from student s where s.level != 'JR'` ??

Comment: I think you are not using join. You are using sub-query.

Comment: What do you mean, this not giving you the expected answer? Please illustrate with input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it doesn't make any sense to do sub query or join in this case while you can get it with simple query like.

```
SELECT level as Seniority, age as Age from student WHERE levels != 'JR'
```

It should give you desired output.

Comment: "," is an alternate spelling for "cross join" that binds less tightly than all the "join" operators.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree a `join` may be overkill, this looks like homework, in which case you may have been asked to specifically use a `join`. Here's my attempt:

```
select distinct levels as Seniority, age as Age
  from student
       natural join
       ( select *
           from student a
          where a.levels != 'JR' );
```